# multiple row data insert give multiple alert in php

Tags: php

hi my problem is when am edit my form which have 3 row and save data its insert in 3 times give 3 javascript alert due to foreach loop

i have no idea where is problem

```
    if(isset($_POST['btn_sub']))
{
    foreach($_POST['marks'] as $row=>$Act)
    {    
        $session=$_GET['session'];
        $cl_name=$_GET['cl_name'];
        $cl_section=$_GET['cl_section'];
        $exam=$_GET['exam'];
        $date=$_GET['date'];
        $subj = $_GET['subj'];

    $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($Act);
    $maxmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['maxmarks'][$row]);
    $passmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passmarks'][$row]);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$row]);
    $rollno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rollno'][$row]);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'][$row]);
    $attendance = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance'][$row]);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ex_marks` WHERE `session`='$session' and `cl_name`='$cl_name' and `cl_section`='$cl_section' and `subject`='$subj' and `exam`='$exam' and `date`='$date' and `roll_no`='$rollno' and `obtainmarks`='$marks'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ex_marks` (`mid`, `session`, `cl_name`, `cl_section`, `name`, `fname`, `status`, `date`, `exam`, `roll_no`, `subject`, `maxmarks`, `passmarks`, `obtainmarks`)
        VALUES('', '$session', '$cl_name', '$cl_section', '$name','$fname', '$attendance', '$date', '$exam', '$rollno', '$subj', '$maxmarks','$passmarks','$marks')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted Successfully!')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Already Exist!')</script>";
    }
}
}
```

see this code

Comment: it mean data already exist which you entering

Answer (score 1):

```
You set $flg value. By using value alert once.    

if(isset($_POST['btn_sub']))
    {
        $flg=0;
        foreach($_POST['marks'] as $row=>$Act)
        {    
            $session=$_GET['session'];
            $cl_name=$_GET['cl_name'];
            $cl_section=$_GET['cl_section'];
            $exam=$_GET['exam'];
            $date=$_GET['date'];
            $subj = $_GET['subj'];

        $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($Act);
        $maxmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['maxmarks'][$row]);
        $passmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passmarks'][$row]);
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$row]);
        $rollno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rollno'][$row]);
        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'][$row]);
        $attendance = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance'][$row]);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ex_marks` WHERE `session`='$session' and `cl_name`='$cl_name' and `cl_section`='$cl_section' and `subject`='$subj' and `exam`='$exam' and `date`='$date' and `roll_no`='$rollno' and `obtainmarks`='$marks'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ex_marks` (`mid`, `session`, `cl_name`, `cl_section`, `name`, `fname`, `status`, `date`, `exam`, `roll_no`, `subject`, `maxmarks`, `passmarks`, `obtainmarks`)
            VALUES('', '$session', '$cl_name', '$cl_section', '$name','$fname', '$attendance', '$date', '$exam', '$rollno', '$subj', '$maxmarks','$passmarks','$marks')") or die(mysql_error());
            $flg=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $flg=0;
            exit;
        }
    }
    if($flg==1)
    {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted Successfully!')</script>";    
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Already Exist!')</script>";
    }
    }
```

Comment: tnx now got one alert but now problem is only 1st row save max mark and pass marks save in only 1st row and obtain marks save in all rows ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo javascript all the time in loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_sub']))


{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['marks'] as $row=>$Act)
    {   
    $i++;
        $session=$_GET['session'];
        $cl_name=$_GET['cl_name'];
        $cl_section=$_GET['cl_section'];
        $exam=$_GET['exam'];
        $date=$_GET['date'];
        $subj = $_GET['subj'];
$marks = mysql_real_escape_string($Act);
$maxmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['maxmarks'][$row]);
$passmarks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passmarks'][$row]);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$row]);
$rollno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rollno'][$row]);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'][$row]);
$attendance = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance'][$row]);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ex_marks` WHERE `session`='$session' and `cl_name`='$cl_name' and `cl_section`='$cl_section' and `subject`='$subj' and `exam`='$exam' and `date`='$date' and `roll_no`='$rollno' and `obtainmarks`='$marks'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ex_marks` (`mid`, `session`, `cl_name`, `cl_section`, `name`, `fname`, `status`, `date`, `exam`, `roll_no`, `subject`, `maxmarks`, `passmarks`, `obtainmarks`)
    VALUES('', '$session', '$cl_name', '$cl_section', '$name','$fname', '$attendance', '$date', '$exam', '$rollno', '$subj', '$maxmarks','$passmarks','$marks')") or die(mysql_error());
    if( $i == 3 ){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted Successfully!')</script>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Already Exist!')</script>";
    exit;
}
}
}
```

$i will decide when to send a success message.

Comment: tnx now got one alert but now problem is only 1st row save max mark and pass marks save in only 1st row and obtain marks save in all rows ..